# Number validation in html form using php

Tags: php, validation, forms, http-post

I have created a form where the amount filed is like

`<label for="amt"<?php validateField( "amt", $Fieldsmissing ) ?>>Amt *</label>`
`<input type="number" name="amt" id="amt" min="1" value="<?php setValue( "amt" ) ?>" />`

and in the top of the form the condition is like

`function setValue( $fieldName ) { if ( isset( $_POST[$fieldName] )  && $_POST[$fieldName] > 0 ) { echo $_POST[$fieldName]; } }`

After submitting, it shows error if I have input 0 however if I put 00 or any '-' sign or any alphabets instead of 0, it does not validates.

As I know that the number type has a bug in Mozila, IE but it works fine in Chrome because Chrome does not accept any input below 1. What I am looking for is, I want to set input value ranging from 0.1 to maximum positive number (i.e 99999). Apart from that, if it inputs anything else it will show error. Can any one please tell me what condition will be best suited for my form.
Thanks.

The full source code is given here for your understanding, it would be appreciated if you have a look on [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/spo0osmlf7wb536/registration.php?n=40292574)

Answer (score 0):

Check out these functions:

- [**intval:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the conversion (the default is base 10). intval() should not be used on objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1.
- [**filter_var:**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) Filters a variable with a specified filter. (`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` in your case.
- [**settype**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) Set the type of a variable. (integer)

So, try this:

```
function setValue($fieldName)
{
   if (isset($_POST[$fieldName]))
   {
      $field = intval($_POST[$fieldname]);
   }

   // other magic
}
```

Comment: it is not working while putting 00 or any alphabets. it is only working while putting 0. however when it is showing error for 0, in every field `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: fieldname in <b>/home/content/13/10377813/html/components/com_jumi/files/registration.php</b> on line <b>84</b><br />` is showing into the every single fields.

Comment: yes, instead of $_POST['fieldname'] try $_POST[$fieldname] :)